# Struts 2 s:select with values from resource bundle

Tags: jsp, struts2, ognl, struts-tags

We are using the `s:select` to show a list of string from resource bundle.

In the Action:

```
//bank codes will be something [12,13,14]
List<String> bankCodesList; //with setter and getter
String selectedBankCode;
```

In the message resources each bank will have a name:

```
bank.code.12= ALFM Bank
bank.code.13= RIHN Bank

....
```

In the JSP:

```
   <s:select name = "selectedBankCode" 
             list = "bankCodesList"         
          listKey = "toString()" 
        listValue = "%{getText('bank.code.' + toString())}" />
```

As the bank list is `List<String>` we used `toString()` to get the key and used `toString()` to get value from resource bundle.

I excepted to find the `s:select` has a `status` attribute same as `s:iterator` but I could not find any!

So you think there are better ways?!

Comment: Not sure why you'd expect that; `<s:select>` is meant to be self-contained. It doesn't expose its iteration. Personally I think you should be building this data in the Java layer somewhere and providing it to the tag through the action or a helper.

Comment: Status? Why do you need status? Use `top` keyword.

Comment: +1 @AleksandrM thanks! where do you find this keyword?! I searched a lot!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need to call `toString()` in `listKey` attribute at all so you can remove this attribute. And in `listValue` you can use `top` keyword.

```xml
<s:select name = "selectedBankCode" 
          list = "bankCodesList" 
     listValue = "%{getText('bank.code.' + top)}" />
```

The `top` keyword is mentioned [here](http://struts.apache.org/development/2.x/docs/ognl-basics.html#OGNLBasics-DifferencesfromtheWebWork1.xEL) and [here](http://struts.apache.org/development/2.x/docs/iterator.html) in the examples.