# Using top object in Struts 2.5

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, ognl

According to [s2-026](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/plugins/servlet/mobile?contentId=61317915#content/view/61317915):

> Support for expression using top will be dropped in upcoming Struts
> version 2.5!

We used the **`top`**  object in lots of JSP pages as below (which shows a list of `currencyTypes` and look up the name from Struts messages):

```jsp
<s:select name = "selectedCurrencyType" 
          list = "currencyTypes"
       listKey = "top" 
     listValue = "%{getText('acc.currencyType.'+top)}" />
```

It currently works with struts `2.3.24.1` but according to above comment, will above select box works for `2.5`, or we will not have the top reference any more?!

If this is true, please let me know how should we fix above `s:select`?!

Comment: What object referencing it?

Comment: I mean the top object, which represents root of execution context. Will the above select work on 2.5? If not how should we fix it ?!

Comment: @AlirezaFattahi RomanC is asking you which object are you referring to with the `top` keyword. I've supposed it is the current element in an iteration, but it could also be something else so you should be more specific about it

Comment: Ah, `top` object push it on the value stack.

Comment: @AlirezaFattahi what is CurrencyType ?

Comment: @AlirezaFattahi: These kinds of question are better to ask on S2 mailing lists.

Comment: @AndreaLigios it is a `simple List<String>`

Comment: @RomanC yes this the current element in iteration same as http://struts.apache.org/docs/iterator.html and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23494891/struts-2-sselect-with-values-from-resource-bundle thanks !!

Comment: Go back to the toString() way then, if it worked in listValue you're good.

Comment: Support for `top` object was added to support internal operations, it shouldn't be used by users (yes, expressing that in docs was a bad idea :( )

Anyway, looks like we must prepare a migration path or keep support for `top`

Comment: @LukaszLenart Thanks, please send it as an answer so I can add mark it as answered!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Support for `top` object was added to support internal operations, it shouldn't be used by users (yes, expressing that in docs was a bad idea :( )

Anyway, looks like we must prepare a migration path or keep support for the `top` object.

Answer (score 1):

What I found in this documentation and what I use in my example [Passing parameters to action through ModelDriven in Struts 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21282400/passing-parameters-to-action-through-modeldriven-in-struts-2) the `top` object is a element of the `CompaundRoot`. And this class has a [`cutStack()`](http://struts.apache.org/maven/struts2-core/apidocs/com/opensymphony/xwork2/util/CompoundRoot.html#cutStack(int)) method that is mentioned in

> With expression like `[0] ... [3]` etc. Struts 2 will cut the stack and
>   still return back a `CompoundRoot` object. To get the top of that
>   particular stack cut, use `0.top`.

The last expression is a typo for `[xxx].top` where `xxx` is the index of the `CompoundRoot` object. And this object could be referenced as `[xxx]`. It is a `top` object cut to the `xxx` index.