# Sruts2 <s:radio /> with label read from .properties file

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, radio-button, struts-tags

I am migrating the code from Struts1 to Struts2 where I have the following scenario:

```xml
<html:radio property="case" value="A" onclick="radioClickA();"/>
<bean:message key="label.A"/>

<html:radio property="case" value="B" onclick="radioClickB();"/>
<bean:message key="label.B"/> 

<html:radio property="case" value="C" onclick="radioClickC();"/>
<bean:message key="label.C"/>
```

Since in Struts2 we have to add all the above three radio buttons in one list, how can I add the localized label for each radio button ?

Comment: *Since in Struts2 we have to add all the above three radio buttons in one list* - You **can**, doesn't mean you **have to**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `A`,`B`,`C` to be Strings:

```
@Getter         private String[] cases = {"A","B","C"};
        @Setter private String case;
```

```xml
<s:radio name = "case" 
         list = "cases"
 listLabelKey = "%{'label.' + top}" 
      onclick = "radioClick(this.value);"
/>
```

Note that the `top` keyword was intended for internal use only, 
and [its usage might be inhibited in future versions of Struts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32885612/1654265).

Then you can use `toString()`, less elegant but rock-solid:

```xml
<s:radio name = "case" 
         list = "cases"
 listLabelKey = "%{'label.' + toString()}" 
      onclick = 'radioClick(this.value);'
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have wrote in different way and it worked.

```xml
<s:radio theme = "simple" 
          name = "case" 
          list = "#{'A':getText('label.A'), 'B':getText('label.B'), 'C':getText('label.C')}" 
       onclick = "radioClick();" 
/>
```

Comment: Yes, this is another way, for small lists I use it too (but usually in <s:select /> only)

Comment: @swetha  I tried your solution but I this error occured:   `org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Error on line 31, column 9 in template/simple/radiomap.ftl
stack.findString(parameters.listValue) is undefined.
It cannot be assigned to itemValue - Class: freemarker.core.Assignment`