# doubleselect in Struts2 using a Map

Tags: java, struts2

I'm trying to use `doubleselect` tag from Struts2 by using this [link](http://thefiles.macadamian.com/2008/04/struts-2-doubleselect-detailed-example.html) as a guide. When I select the telephone country code (ex: 91, 92, 216), it should display three cities from that country.

For this I have a `Map<Integer, List<String>`. Below is the tag.

```xml
<s:doubleselect 
   name="obj.countryCode" id="countryCode" list="countryCodeCityNameMap.keySet()"
   doubleName="obj.cityName" doubleId="cityName" doubleList="countryCodeCityNameMap" />
```

This yields a different output. In the first drop-down it displays the country code properly. But irrespective of the selected value in the first drop-down it always shows all the values in the second drop-down like this:

```
[aaa,bbb,ccc]
[ddd,eee,fff]
[ggg,hhh,iii]
```

How can i use the Map to get the desired output? 
Should I create a structure like this as per the given link:

```
List<Makes> // in first drop-down
Makes contains makeId, modelId and List<Models> // List<Models> in second drop-down
Models contains modelId and modelName
```

If yes, then how does my scenario fit in to this model?

Comment: Your scenarion doesn't, you didn't post any code related to you model. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IF  [the `top` object is still available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32816417/struts-2-top-object-in-struts-2-5), you should be able to subfilter the inner list using it like follows:

```xml
<s:doubleselect 
         name="obj.countryCode"    id="countryCode"    list="countryCodeCityNameMap.keySet()"
   doubleName="obj.cityName" doubleId="cityName" doubleList="countryCodeCityNameMap.get(top)"
/>
```